# other requests are not accepted in timely manner by apache due to comet implementation

Tags: php, apache, comet, long-polling, keep-alive

hi i have implemented comet(long polling request) base application where my application updates content based on server response

my php code is as below,my application uses zend framework

```
ini_set('set_time_limit', 300);
//get zend session object
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
//get zend_auth object
$auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$requestTime=time();
$response=array();
$response["returnvalue"]="invalid";
//check for new event on server for 240 seconds else send response
do{
    //call_function return true or false
    $query=$this->call_function($auth->getIdentity()->user_id,$auth->getIdentity()->lastViewedTime);
//some code here
if(!$query){
    //sleep for some time;
    sleep(60);
}else{
    //send response to server when something new has occured
            $lastViewed=round(microtime(true) * 1000);
            $user=$auth->getStorage()->read();
            $user->lastViewedTime=$lastViewed;
            $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
    $response["returnvalue"]="valid";
    break;
}
}while(true && (time()-$requestTime)<240);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);exit;
```

my javascript code is

```
var counter = {
'poll' : function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/long-polling',
       data:"a=b",
       dataType:"json",
       async:true,
       success:function(response){
           counter.update(response);
       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
            alert("This Operation Could not be Completed. Please check your Internet Connection and try Again. If problem persists please contact Support");
        }
    });

},
'update' : function(json) {
    alert(json.data);
    counter.poll();
 }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  counter.poll();
});
```

my apache configurations are

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 240
MaxClients 150
MaxRequestsPerChild 4
```

long polling is working fine,but problem is when browser sends other request to load other elements,images on server,server do not reply/blocks request till 5 mins

any suggetions??

Comment: You're not showing that in your code, you should amend that - it's probably your problem: [PHP/Apache blocking on each request?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/430750)

Comment: ok,will remove session code and try it again

Comment: session was my problem thanx @Pekka,resolved it by adding Zend_Session::writeClose(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session was my problem thanx ,resolved it by adding Zend_Session::writeClose(true);