# Website not responding until a long HTTP request has finished or another browser is used (Cloudflare-related?)

Tags: http, firefox, browser, phpmyadmin, cloudflare

I have often noticed that when I execute an HTTP request that takes a long time to process (e.g. a time-consuming MySQL query through phpMyAdmin) or a big file upload (in one request), a website stops responding to new requests until the previous long HTTP request has completed. If I try to open a webpage of the same website/domain in a new browser tab (or window), it does not respond. However, if I open incognito mode or another browser and try to open the same webpage, it responds. Therefore, it is not that the server executing the request becomes overloaded.

The websites I have experienced this with are behind Cloudflare. I suspect this might be related to how Cloudflare handles proxying the traffic, but I am not sure.

For reference, I usually use Mozilla Firefox.

I have searched all around the internet about this issue but could not find anything. I am posting this question in case someone else has experienced this and/or might know what causes it.

**Edit:**

The websites I have tested on are mine and the issue is not related to any custom rate limiting that I have set explicitly.
I don't think the problem is directly related to phpMyAdmin. I mentioned it as an example. The StackOverflow questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405658/long-request-blocks-other-requests-in-apache-and-php) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430750/php-apache-blocking-on-each-request)) could be related to my problem. My websites (as the one in the example I gave) and phpMyAdmin all make use of PHP sessions if this is the type of sessions the StackOverflow answers refer to, so this could indeed be one of the reasons if that is true.

However, for the last few weeks, I have been experiencing an even more strange issue (probably unrelated to the one described in my StackOverflow question) where randomly a website x.com would stop responding, and then even its subdomains a.x.com and b.com, even though all of them are served by completely different servers in different data centers and different countries. The only common things between these domains in this case are that all of them are part of the same higher-level domain (x.com) and Cloudflare is a reverse proxy for for all of them. Some of those domains serve requests for static files, so there is no script execution happening on an HTTP request and no application sessions (apart from possibly HTTP or TLS sessions, depending on how Cloudflare handles proxying). I am completely sure that the issue is not caused by the origin server configurations on my side. So, it is either something related to Cloudflare or something is wrong with my web browser. However, this second issue is likely a different issue from the one in my original question.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to phpMyAdmin or Firefox?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405658/long-request-blocks-other-requests-in-apache-and-php helps?

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430750/php-apache-blocking-on-each-request

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't think the problem is directly related to phpMyAdmin. I mentioned them as examples. The StackOverflow questions you referenced could be related to my problem. My websites (as the one in the example I gave) and phpMyAdmin all make use of PHP sessions if this is the type of sessions the StackOverflow answers refer to, so this could indeed be one of the reasons if that is true.

Comment: @NicoHaase However, for the last few weeks, I have been experiencing an even more strange issue (probably unrelated to the one described in my StackOverflow question) where randomly a website x.com would stop responding and then even its subdomains a.x.com and b.com even though all of them are served by completely different servers in different data centers and different countries. The only common things between these domains in this case are that all of them are part of the same higher-level domain (x.com) and Cloudflare is a reverse proxy for for all of them.

Comment: @NicoHaase Continuing about the second problem: Some of those domains serve requests for static files, so there is no script execution happening on an HTTP request and no application sessions (apart from possibly HTTP or TLS sessions, depending on how Cloudflare handles proxying). I am completely sure that the issue is not caused by the origin server configurations on my side. So, it is either something related to Cloudflare or something is wrong with my web browser. However, this second issue is likely a different issue from the one in my original question.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section